# Reading large XLS and XLSX excel format

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to reading large excel files which has size around 40MB to 50MB.
For XLSX i used OPCPackage it solved the problem,but now I am facing problem with XLS format.
When I use normal POI like POIFSFileSystem to read files, I am getting java **heap space error**.
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Basically we are converting excel files to tab-delimited files.

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(sourceFile.getPath(),
            PackageAccess.READ);
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Used HSSFListener to process the file.

Answer (score 2):

As [explained in the Apache POI documentation, don't open with an InputStream when you have a File!](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

For a `.xls` file, you should make sure you're using a new version of Apache POI, then open the container with [new POIFSFileSystem(File)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.html#POIFSFileSystem%28java.io.File%29), eg

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new File("input.xls"));
// HSSF Event parsing code goes here
```

Otherwise, make sure you use the [HSSF event api](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api) if memory is a concern, and likely the [record-aware event api](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#record_aware_event_api) if you need to ensure you detect missing cells

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your program, you need to specify a larger maximum heap size with -Xmx2g (for a max of 2 gig). See "man java".

Comment: thanks for reply.I want test it on ideal system.moreover i tried with that but still same error.